# How to set content to Spinner elements when an element is selected?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, spinner, android-spinner

I am new to Android programming and was learning about Spinner concept. I tried to create one and was successful, however, I needed help setting content to the elements. I mean, say 3 elements as `Home`, `School` , and `Office` are added to a spinner, I want the `Home` address to be displayed when I select `Home` from the list, `School` address when school is selected and the same for the office.

Also,please let me know if its possible to code in the Java class or there's an 'XML way' only.One more problem is that the first element always shows up in the spinner. How do I put something else there like "select".

Please let me know how to proceed.
The elements of the spinner are `Home` `School` and `Office`.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, show us what you have tried so far. Read http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask